# Ruby on rails routing is displaying only show view for index and edit action methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created one controller and added default 7 action methods , I have also created 4 views and those are index , new , show , edit all contains difeent data

```
also added resources :posts controller configuration into my routing file as well 
'
My problem is when i try to navigate to index or edit views using url .. it displays me only show views , however index method is working as a default 

below are my urls `enter code here`
```

1 . http://localhost:3000/posts/index[^]

if i try this it gives me show view data

2. localhost:3000/posts

this gives me proper index data (default without mentioning index action name)

3. http://localhost:3000/posts/edit[^]

this one but always shows me data present in show view and not in data present in edit view

Please suggest

Below are few lines from my route file.

```
Hide   Copy Code
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'
  resources :posts

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'home#index'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [Rails guide entry on default resource routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions), there's nothing unusual going on here.

`/posts` is how you access your `posts#index`, not `/posts/index`.

For show and edit, you need your post id in the URL so that Rails knows which record to retrieve, ie `/posts/1/edit`

Comment: ok , thanks . I understood . But one doubt i have here why /posts/index or
/posts/edit is navigating me to show view . insted it should resource not found error same like asp.net mvc ,'
Actually i am new on ruby on rails and trying to understand few concepts behind this

Comment: Would depend on your controller's show action.  What is the code for fetching the resource?  If it is something like @post = Post.find(params [:id]) then yes you should get an error (unless you have a post with id "edit" :p)

Answer (score 0):

You can run `rake routes` from the console to see all of your routes.  The result of `resources :posts` should be the following seven routes:

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
           POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_sheet GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_sheet GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     sheet GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
           PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
           PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
           DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
```

Rails will match the URL to the URI pattern and take the matching controller action.  btw you can use `rake routes CONTROLLER=posts` to see just the routes for `posts`.